# How to Get a Div Centered and Get it to Overlap Other Items in the HTML

Tags: html, css

I have run into some problems with trying to get this div centered and get it to overlap other items in the HTML, what it is now is just really messy, it would be great if you could help, thanks.

Here is the CSS:

```
#gameoverbox {
  border: 7px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 210px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -70px;
}
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
a:active {
  color: green;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#thebuttonovergame {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<center>
  <div id="gameoverbox">

    <h1>GAME OVER</h1>
    <h1>GREAT SCORE!</h1>
    <br>

    <center>
      <div id="thebuttonovergame">

        <a href="#" id="tryagainbutton">
          <h1>PLAY</h1>
        </a>

        <br>

        <a href="#" id="backhomebutton">
          <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
        </a>

      </div>
    </center>
```

Comment: What is it that you want to be centered?

Comment: game over div? you dont have such a div in your HTML that is posted.

Comment: Just saw this, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Can you be more specific or add a link to an image to see what you want exactly achive

Comment: you can't have `position: absolute` and `position: relative` on the same element.. it can only be one or the other.. in this case it is taking `position: relative`.. the last css applied is the most important unless overridden with `!important` (do not use `!important`.. ever..)

Comment: Sorry I meant the gameoverbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you exactly want but try with this case an let me know if works for you

**1-** Center the div with transform

```css
#gameoverbox {
  border: 7px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 210px;
  position: relative;    
}
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
a:active {
  color: green;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#thebuttonovergame {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div id="gameoverbox">

    <h1>GAME OVER</h1>
    <h1>GREAT SCORE!</h1>
    <br>

    <center>
      <div id="thebuttonovergame">

        <a href="#" id="tryagainbutton">
          <h1>PLAY</h1>
        </a>

        <br>

        <a href="#" id="backhomebutton">
          <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
        </a>

      </div>
    </center>
```

**2-** Center the div inside the `gameoverbox` removing `position: absolute` and adding `display: inline-block`

```css
#gameoverbox {
  border: 7px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;    
}
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
a:active {
  color: green;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#thebuttonovergame {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div id="gameoverbox">

    <h1>GAME OVER</h1>
    <h1>GREAT SCORE!</h1>
    <br>

    <center>
      <div id="thebuttonovergame">

        <a href="#" id="tryagainbutton">
          <h1>PLAY</h1>
        </a>

        <br>

        <a href="#" id="backhomebutton">
          <h1>HOME PAGE</h1>
        </a>

      </div>
    </center>
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I actually forgot to put something on the HTML there, can you help me get the button over div into this div:                                 <div id="gameoverbox"> <h1>GAME OVER</h1> <h1>GREAT SCORE!</h1>

Comment: @MathewJahnes I update the answer to fit you new html let me know if now works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

These changes move the `thebuttonovergame` div into the center regardless of other elements on the page.

**See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrsrL8jg/)**

```
#thebuttonovergame {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

Comment: removing position: absolute will not allow the element to be over the other elements.

Comment: leave `position: absolute` and add `left: 0; right: 0; top: x;` where `x=padding from the top that fits for this object`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I actually forgot to put something on the HTML there, can you help me get the button over div into this div: <div id="gameoverbox"> <h1>GAME OVER</h1> <h1>GREAT SCORE!</h1>

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question very straightforward:

1) To center, you need some kind of margin applied to the object you desire centered. The `<center>` tag [is not HTML5 supported](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_deprecated_tags.htm), so I would suggest omitting it

2) To go over other elements, you will need some z-indexes defined on your objects, which usually means at least a relative position defined on them.

I took your sample code and provided a jsfiddle with what I think you are trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/0tdgnapn/

**Note:** I am using negative `margin-top` property to move the content over your `<h1>` tags, but you could use other positioning properties.

Best of luck

Comment: I know you chose to use negative margin, but that isn't the best use case here... Should probably lean more towards using top esp with position: absolute

Comment: Thanks, sorry I actually forgot to put something on the HTML there,   can you help me get the button over div into this div:                                  <div id="gameoverbox">

    <h1>GAME OVER</h1>
    <h1>GREAT SCORE!</h1>
    <br>

Comment: sure. I replaced the HTML in my fiddle with your updated question and used the `top` property for moving the div, as recommended: http://jsfiddle.net/0tdgnapn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use center tags; just use CSS instead. I'd write the butttonovergame div's style like this:

```
#thebuttonovergame: {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #98BF21;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Setting the margin like that centres block elements, which divs already are.